# Retrieving the last printed character on console

Tags: python

I'd like to get the last character written on the console in python.
For example I may have several threads which write on the console then in each of the threads I need to know the last character that has been written to the console by other threads. Is there any way?

e.g:
`>> print 'Hello'`
the last character is '\n' in this case
or

```
Thread A:
>>> print 'Hello'
Thread B:
>>> print 'Bye'
Thread C:
>>> What is the last written character?
```

And it's obvious we can't determine the answer in thread C unless we ask the Console in some way.

Comment: what you mean `last character in python` ?

Comment: @howaboutNO
>> print 'Hello'
the last character is '\n' in this case

Comment: If several threads write to the console, what is the last character?

Answer (score 3):

Depends on where you're writing to. If you're writing to standard output `sys.stdout` (the usual case) - it's not open for reading. So technically no. What you **could** do is use a pipe the output to someone else and grab it after stdout already flushed it.

This is an example under Ubuntu OS, but there are probably equivalents in any OS:

And example script (`p.py`):

```
print "hello"
```

Take the first of last **two** characters to skip newline (`\n`) from `print`:

```
reut@sharabani:~$ python p.py | tail -c2 | head -c1
o
```

### Edit:

If you do not have access to `head` and `tail` it should be simple to do this in python:

write the script `take_last_char.py`:

```
import sys
# read whatever output the previous script piped here
# but only keep the last line (stripping the newline...)
for line in sys.stdin:
    tmp = line.strip()

print tmp[-1]
```

And now simply use:

```
python p.py | python take_last_char.py
```

Comment: the problem is that I'm writing to stdout

Comment: This "workaround" **works** if you're writing to stdout. That's why I wrote it :)

Comment: it's kinda OS depended, isn't it?

Comment: Yes. I should mention it, but this probably has an equivalent in any OS.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you change `end` parameter of `print` function in your program, it'll be always `\n`.

Comment: however the question was something else, bu it helped indeed, thanks :-)